# Script to Automatically Run SQL File

Tags: sql, unix, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I want a schedule job  to run a function/Sql File in SQL Developer without using scheduler in orcale since I only have limited access to the database. Since my function always deletes when database refresh I need to run my function again. I want it to not manually run my sql file. Is this possible using unix script or is there any program I could use for fhis.

P.S It's okay if I need to trigger its using button or something as long as I don't need to run it every refresh of the database. Thanks

Comment: Why not just build a trigger? The trigger will execute each time something happens so you do not have to schedule it, the trigger will only do the change when something happens.

Comment: Everyday the database will refresh and I guess trigger will also be deleted

Comment: does it refresh daily at a certain time?

Comment: Yes. Basically all the scripts I ran will be deleted after database refreshed.

Comment: then cron should be fine. if you refresh at 5am you run the crontab at 5.01am or something like that

Comment: I'm thinking of using task scheduler in windows then run a unix scirpt to run my function

Comment: is this on windows or on unix where you need to run it?